# Howto: Intercept a a4j request using a javax.servlet.Filter?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, servlet-filters, ajax4jsf

Does anybody know how to intercept a a4j request using a javax.servlet.Filter?
The interception must occur before FacesServlet be called (it's why I'm planning to do it using Filter).

I'd like to know which method will be executed on my backbean, cause I need to do a dynamic control first.

Answer (score 0):

You'd like to determine the request headers for a marker of the a4j request. I don't do a4j, but if it is doing its work well, you should be able to determine it based on the `X-Requested-With` header.

```
String requestedWith = request.getHeader("X-Requested-With");
```

Then just determine in an `if` block if the value is the expected one for a4j requests and handle accordingly. Don't forget to continue the filter chain at end whenever neccessary.

```
if (requestedWith.equals(someAjax4jsfSpecificValue)) {
    // Do your job.
}
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

To get it to run, just map it on the `<servlet-name>` of the `FacesServlet` as it is currently definied in `web.xml`.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>yourFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```